# I need to prove trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I need to prove that

> $$\tan(2x) = \frac{ 2\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x)  }{ \cos^2 (x) - \sin^2 (x)}$$

Not sure where to go

Comment: try $\tan 2x=\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}$

Comment: or just double angle formula for $\tan$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x\;,\;\;2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sin { \left( 2x \right)  } =2\sin { \left( x \right) \cos { \left( x \right)  }  } \\ \cos { \left( 2x \right)  } =\cos ^{ 2 }{ \left( x \right) -\sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( x \right)  }  } $$

Answer (score 0):

If you know $\sin(2x)=2sinxcosx$ and $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$

Then $\tan(2x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$